# Salesforce Apex web service test class error

Tags: apex, unit-test, soap

I'm working on `Salesforce Apex web service` to create record. Below is the apex web service class that I have written:

```
global class createCloudRecord {

    global class projectInputs{
        webService Integer ProjectID;
        webService String ProjectName;
    }

    webService static Boolean createSFRecords(List<projectInputs> inputs) {

        cv__Designation__c desg = new cv__Designation__c();
        desg.cv__Active__c = true;
        desg.cv__Default__c = false;
        desg.cv__Description__c = 'Test Desc';
        desg.OwnerId = '002B0000000K9soIAD';
        desg.Name = inputs[0].ProjectName;
        desg.cv__ExternalId__c = string.valueof(inputs[0].ProjectID);

        insert desg;

        return true;
    }
}
```

It's working fine and creating records on `SF cloud via SOAP API call`. Now I have to written the test class for above web service with code coverage of `min 75%.`

Below is the code that I have written for my test class:

```
@isTest 
private class createCloudRecordTest {

    static testMethod void testCreateSFRecords() {
         createCloudRecord.projectInputs project = new createCloudRecord.projectInputs();
         project.ProjectID = 12345;
         project.ProjectName = 'TestProject';


        createCloudRecord.createSFRecords(project);
    }
}
```

But this is showing an error for this line `createCloudRecord.createSFRecords(project);`:

> Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature.
>   Anyone has any idea how can I make this working.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share code of createDesignationCampaign class

Comment: Updated my question that's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your web service method you are passing list as the parameter where as in your test class it is just a single record:

```
@isTest 
private class createCloudRecordTest {

    static testMethod void testCreateSFRecords() {
         createCloudRecord.projectInputs project = new createCloudRecord.projectInputs();
         project.ProjectID = 12345;
         project.ProjectName = 'TestProject';
         list<createCloudRecord.projectInputs> projects = new list<createCloudRecord.projectInputs>();
         projects.add(project);

        createCloudRecord.createSFRecords(projects);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Let me try this and get back to you!

Comment: Thank you so much @Nitin. It's working fine now and I got 100% code coverage. Have a great day!

Comment: Happy to help :)